# Passing arrays as parameters via log4j.xml & log4j.properties

Tags: java, java-8, log4j

Can some one let me know is it possible to pass array or list to a log4j appender property via `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties`?

Something like below in appender I want to populate via `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties`

```
private List<String> validPackages;

public List<String> getValidPackages() {
        return buildVersionFile;
}

public void setValidPackages(List<String> validPackages) {
        this.validPackages = validPackages
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in log4j [mailing list](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Passing-arrays-as-parameters-via-log4j-xml-amp-log4j-properties-td76123.html) we can not just pass the properties in log4j . We have to implement a plugin

> I haven't tested this out, but from the plugin documentation < 
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html>, if you make
>   a  plugin that implements Collection, then you can automatically
>   convert its  children into that collection. In that use case, though,
>   you'd need another  plugin element for your validPackages list instead
>   of a plain String.
>
> There's no built-in TypeConverter for arrays (other than byte[] and
>   char[]  which have special meaning anyways), so another alternative
>   would be to add  a TypeConverter for Collection or similar,
>   though reifying generics  at that point for more general Collection
>   usage would become an exercise  in frustration IMO.